# passing cmd line input parameters to GNU scripts run in Win7 batch files

Tags: batch-file, parameters, cmd, format, set

A batch file has to first process and print out some data from the datafile to let me select proper parameters %2 and %3 for later use. Next, I have to enter manually those two select parameters.

What syntax should I use to request and input several parameters, possibly using the SET /p command on a Win7 Pro box, when a batch file is being run, so that these parameters are then passed on to various GNU utilities which expect the %1 parameter format? Here's an example of a run.bat file and its use:

```
C:\run <datafile>
@set /p pattern1=Enter pattern1:
@set /p pattern2=Enter pattern2:
@awk '/%1/,/%2/' datafile
```

This example should print all the lines between, and inclusive of, two strings pattern1 and pattern2 from , but whatever parameter format I try for pattern1 with the set /p command (%1, %%1, %1%,...), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%1` , `%2` and so on are command line parameters, you can start a batch with it:

```
run.bat "pattern1" "pattern2" "datafile"
```

and `run.bat`:

```
@echo off &setlocal
awk "/%~1/,/%~2/" "%~3"
```

and with `set /p` you can interactively set variable values:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "pattern1=Enter first pattern: "
set /p "pattern2=Enter second pattern: "
set /p "datafile=Enter data file name: "
awk "/%pattern1%/,/%pattern2%/" "%datafile%"
```